# Collapse bootstrap navbar when scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

Would it be possible to collapse a bootstrap fixed navigation bar when scroll down the page?

It would be the same behavior as is happening when the windows size is below the 768px default breakpoint.

Does anyone know how to do it?

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <div id="menu-toggle" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <div class="one"></div>
        <div class="two"></div>
        <div class="three"></div>
      </div>
      <a class="navbar-brand navigation-logo" href="#" title="Logo">
        <img src="/images/logo.svg" alt="Logo" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: please add some code.

Comment: its possible yes. just write the code and make it happen. you the programmer. if you get stuck with a specific error, please feel free to ask.

Comment: What have you tried so far for the collapse on scroll?